# Possibility of poles with positive real part in RLC filter

Tags: education

are there the poles with positive real part in any function mode of the RLC filter?

[image]

The equation to determine the poles is the following:

$$RLCs^2+Ls+R=0$$

$$s_{1,2}=\frac{-L\pm \sqrt {L^2-4R^2LC}}{2RLC}$$

Thank you for your time.

P.s. I posted this question because my professor said that the poles have always real part negative or zero.

Comment: R,L,C are positives.

Comment: If \$ \sqrt{L^2-4R^2LC}>-L \$ then there is a pole with positive real part: \$ s=\frac{-L +\sqrt{L^2-4R^2LC}}{2RLC} \$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Do the math for \$s_{1,2}\$, looking at the numerator. Assuming no component is zero, the term \$\sqrt{L^2 - 4R^2 LC}\$ will have a real part no larger than \$L\$. Therefore, the real part of \$-L \pm \sqrt{L^2 - 4R^2 LC}\$ will have a range of \$(0, -L]\$. This gives the result your professor arrived at.

This analysis is valid for the expected linear, positive-valued devices implied by the question and your professor's response. This result does not necessarily hold for non-linear devices that exhibit negative resistances.

Comment: This doesn't take into account circuits with negative resistance.

Comment: Given that this is a linear component analysis problem, this is over-complicating the analysis. A Gunn diode certainly isn't an introductory circuits component.

Comment: The question's author doesn't specify whether or not he is considering purely passive components and negative resistance circuits are used in many designs (especially RF/microwave oscillators) to replace active components when the additional complexity of the full circuit is not required.

Comment: @Captainj2001 to continue in the vein of your overly pedantic comment, if you did have a negative resistance in there (and it need not be a gunn diode either - a gyrator would work as well) it is no longer a filter but an oscillator as you pointed out.

Comment: @placeholder There is also a large body of research on negative resistance filters. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=negative%20resistance%20filter

Comment: @Captainj2001 cool !! I didn't realize that such complex systems could be described by $$RLCs^2+Ls+R=0$$

Comment: @placeholder This is not very constructive, enjoy your day.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have poles in the real half of the complex plane is to have a circuit in which the "resistance" is negative, i.e., the active circuit replacing the load can be modeled as a negative resistance at some operating point. For instance, if the resistor was a Gunn diode operating in it's region of negative resistance, or an amplifier circuit.

With purely passive components the poles will always be in the left-hand plane or on the imaginary axis.